# Ionic 3 native SQLite plugin is not working as expected

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I use Ionic 3 [native SQLite plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/). But below code is not working as expected. i.e. I cannot see `console.log()` data for the inserted data. It seems I'm doing wrong here. Can you tell me the right way?

Note: No errors. Just not working.

```
  storeApiKeyInSqlite(key: string, name: string) {
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'MyInvoices.db',
      location: 'default'
    }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
      db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Apikeys(Id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, ApiKey NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, ApiName NVARCHAR(100) NULL)', [])
        .then(() => {
          db.executeSql('INSERT INTO Apikeys VALUES(NULL,?,?)', [key, name])
            .then(() => {
              db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Apikeys', [])
                .then(res => {
                  if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                    console.log(res.rows.item(0).Id);
                    console.log(res.rows.item(0).ApiKey);
                    console.log(res.rows.item(0).ApiName);
                  }
                })
                .catch(e => {
                  console.log(e);
                });
            }).catch(e => {
              e => console.log(e)
            });
        }).catch(e => console.log(e));


    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
```

Comment: I know that this does not fix  your issue , but it's just a suggestion  : use TypeORM  , it saved me a huge amount of time

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you? Where should I type it? @FarabiAbdelwahed

Comment: i was referring to https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm

Comment: its sql.. `(Id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL` you cant insert null there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Op's feedback:**

This is the working solution for me:

```
 storeApiKeyInSqlite(key: string, name: string) {
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'MyInvoices.db',
      location: 'default'
    }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
      db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Apikeys(rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,ApiKey NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, ApiName NVARCHAR(100) NULL)', [])
        .then(() => {
          db.executeSql('INSERT INTO Apikeys VALUES(NULL,?,?)', [key, name])
            .then(() => {
              db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Apikeys', [])
                .then(res => {
                  if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                    console.log(res.rows.item(0).rowid);
                    console.log(res.rows.item(0).ApiKey);
                    console.log(res.rows.item(0).ApiName);
                  }
                })
                .catch(e => {
                  console.log(e);
                });
            }).catch(e => {
              console.log(e)
            });
        }).catch(e => console.log(e));
    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
```

**Original answer:**

You cant insert `NULL` for a `PRIMARY KEY` which you explicitly set as `NOT NULL`.

Make a query to:

```
db.executeSql('INSERT INTO Apikeys(ApiKey,ApiName) VALUES(?,?)', [key, name])
            .then(() => {
              db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Apikeys', [])
                .then(res => {
                  if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                    console.log(res.rows.item(0).Id);
                    console.log(res.rows.item(0).ApiKey);
                    console.log(res.rows.item(0).ApiName);
                  }
                })
                .catch(e => {
                  console.log(e);
                });
            }).catch(e => {
              e => console.log(e)
            });
```

Comment: I got that from here `4. Create new Page of Adding New Data`. https://www.djamware.com/post/59c53a1280aca768e4d2b143/ionic-3-angular-4-and-sqlite-crud-offline-mobile-app

Comment: Sorry, I canot test your solution now since we have API issue right now.

Comment: Then this is the error: `{message: "sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: table Apikeys has 3 columns but 2 values were supplied", code: 5}
code
:
5
message
:
"sqlite3_prepare_v2 failure: table Apikeys has 3 columns but 2 values were supplied"
__proto__
:
Object`

Comment: @Sampath I suggest setting `primary key autoincrement` or change `Id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL` to just `Id INT PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: `AUTOINCREMENT` is not a good solution with `SQLite`. Please see this: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-autoincrement/

Comment: yeah.. So I suggested to remove `NOT NULL` for your key